# How to pass dynamically generated IDs to s:url in Struts2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am dynamically populating a table. And I would like to allow the user to delete individual rows using AJAX.

I am using Struts2, jQuery 1.5.x and Struts-JQuery Plugin.

The code in question looks like:

```
<s:url id="delete#{stat.index}" value="delete.action"> 
  <s:param name="id" value="myRowId"></s:param> 
</s:url> 
<sj:a id="deleteRowLink" href="%{delete#{stat.index}}" targets="targetDiv" button="true"> 
  Delete 
</sj:a>
```

The s:url tag's id attribute does not allow me to pass the dynamic index. And if I don't do that, then the generated code is effective only on the last row of data.

Please advise.

Best Regards,

Ashish.

Comment: Found the solution. The issue is with the sj:a tag and not s:url. I changed s:url to use id="delete" and same id accessed in sj:a. And removed the id tag on sj:a and all works fine now.

Comment: Please close the question, if it is resolved or post what you have stated into an answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The issue is with the sj:a tag and not s:url. I changed s:url to use id="delete" and same id accessed in sj:a. And removed the id tag on sj:a and all works fine now.